# Excel C# Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, excel, string, input, was

We create a input of excel and this work fine in localhost(windows server 2012 r2), but when we put in a application server he appears this meessage "Input string was not in a correct format" we think that be a DATE in excel, but we cant reply in localhost.

So any ideas about test?

*points u r using "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" 
*exist other function for input excel and works fine but dont have the field date

thank you guys :)

Comment: Is the app server set to a different culture?

Comment: is the same culture for both

Comment: Could you provide the cultures on each machine, as well as what the data looks like? You could just read the XML file and dump the cell's value somewhere (console / text) that way you'll be able to see if it's really what is causing the problem. Please be aware as well that though the machine's may have the same culture, there's always the possibility the thread is doing something else culture wise. We'll need some more information to help you effectively.